# Is there a possibility of educational redirection for an IT student?

Tags: job

I am a student at an IT school, I study to become a computer engineer.
During my scholarship, what I did was:

- 6 month intership at the beginning of 2nd year.
- 6 month internship at the end of my third year (before the master began).

Both internship subject were about `Java backend`.

Today, I am at the first year of my master (I just finished my third year), but I actually decided to do a sabbatical year, because I have to do my 4th year at international university.
There are multiple reasons preventing me from continuing my studies for a year (financial, administratives, personal, etc...).

But that doesn't bother me, because I can work at the place of my internship for another year, and then go back to my studies, with more knowledge, money and confidence.

But here is the thing: This year also, I will work as a `Java backend` developer.

My question is:

> I kept doing works and internship as a Java developer, is it possible for me to change my path, and work as security engineer? (My dream job)

**P.S : I am sorry for the tags, I couldn't find great ones.**

Answer (score 2):

Universities do not form "Java developers", they form computer scientists/engineer.

Your experience does give you a specialisation with Java, but this is not everything. While it surely gives you an edge to get a more senior position in that particular area, many of the skills of a Java Developer are in fact Developers skills. And these are the same regardless of what language you are coding with.

Some of these skills are also transferable, being able to solve a problem, to prototype solutions etc. So it is entirely possible to still work in infosec (or even totally non related work for what matters). Focus on the high level competencies you've acquired from your experience.

I would not even call this an educational redirection. It is more of a specialisation, and most courses in computer security would anyway be starting as a master 1 or 2 level.

If your goal is to work in infosec, try to find a university that teaches it as part of their master courses. Getting a diploma from this specialised master would indeed be more valuable for finding a job in the field, though not necessarily a requirement.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to answer. I think, what I may have forgot, is that the skills, I've acquired as Java backend developer, will very likely be useful, regardless of what I will do in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You could start changing by getting expertise in java security problems.

After school you'll be considered a software engineer. It's up to you to get your specialization.

You could start tacking some online certificates regarding security and work on some security jobs. From here on is mostly certifications and experience, so school wont have much impact on your specific field as it already provided you with the broad basics.